# v-bind.sync does not pass object as props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm passing an object as a required prop to a component through `v-bind.sync` but I'm getting an error `Missing required prop: "filters"`

What am I missing here? It doesn't seem to be working [as specified in the documentation:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)

> `v-bind.sync="doc"`:
>
> This passes each property in the `doc` object (e.g. `title`) as an individual prop, then adds `v-on` update listeners for each one.

Here's my component which is called using `<ListFilters v-bind.sync="filters" />`

```
<template>
  <div>{{ filters }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ListFilters',
  props: {
    filters: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Adding a default for `filters` results in the component using the default instead of the parent value.

Comment: Vue version is 2.6.10

Comment: Please edit the question to add extra information rather than adding it in the comments. I suspect you're looking for `:filters.sync="filters"`. Doing it the way you're doing it will pull out the individual properties from your `filters` object and set a prop for each one. Unless you have a `filters.filters` property that isn't what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the highlighted passage you provided, any property in `filters` will be passed to the child component as a property of its own that way. So, it would need to contain another `filters` property (`filters.filters`) for it to be accessible in the child component under that name. To pass the parent's property itself, you would use `v-bind:filters.sync="filters"` instead.